# iOS facebook login not redirecting to home page when using with twitter

Tags: ios

I am using facebook and twitter sharing in my app. 
 Facebook sdk working properly, but when i integrate twitter then facebook redirection showing a black screen.

If i comment twitter code then it works properly.

I can't find the exact reson and solution.

Thanks,

Comment: So add your code if you want us to understand your question.

Comment: Post the code making the problem so you can get a useful answer.